# colima how to pull a specific version of ubuntu layer using --layer=true

Tags: docker, colima

I have a requirement to pull a specific version of ubuntu layer instead of the latest, it looks like with the --layer=true colima just pulls the ubuntu:latest tag, Is there any option to configure it to pull a different ubuntu version layer like ubuntu:focal?

Pull a specific ubuntu version layer using `colima start --layer=true` command